# Mean of monthly data on a yearly basis using groupie

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to get the yearly average return (RET) column of this monthly data grouped on year and CUSIP.
I am expecting the average of the returns for that CUSIP for that year to be same for the month ranges.

For eg if for cusip 000307 and year 2018, I have average as 0.051, then the avg_return  column should have the 0.051 for all that cusip for all the months in that year.

I am doing the following but this is changing value for each of the months"

```
monthly_stock_data['mean_return'] = monthly_stock_data.groupby(by = ['CUSIP' ,'year'])['RET'].transform(lambda x: x.rolling(12, 1).mean())
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One approach can be to split the process in two parts. Below code is not validated for syntax.

```
import pandas as pd 
mean_per_year_per_cusip = monthly_stock_data.groupby(by = ['CUSIP' \
,'year'])['RET'].mean())

final = pd.merge(monthly_stock_data, mean_per_year_per_cusip, \
how='left', left_on=['CUSIP' ,'year'],right_on=['CUSIP' ,'year'])
```